# DNS response and nameservers

Tags: dns, wireshark, nameservers

When we inspect the DNS response after trackroute a website, in Wireshark, which section reflected "the information about nameservers"?

Authority RRS?

Additional RRS?

or within the Answers section (name, type, class, time, data)

Sorry, new to English and Wireshark.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authority section will contain the information about the nameservers.  The "authority" section tells you just that: what servers are "authoritative" for that information.

Example query to .com's name servers for information about www.google.com:

```
> dig @f.gtld-servers.net. www.google.com A

; <<>> DiG 9.7.6-P2 <<>> @f.gtld-servers.net. www.google.com A
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62133
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.                        IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns4.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.google.com.         172800  IN      A       216.239.34.10
ns1.google.com.         172800  IN      A       216.239.32.10
ns3.google.com.         172800  IN      A       216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.         172800  IN      A       216.239.38.10
```

The above answer shows that there is no ANSWER section because .com doesn't know the address for google's A record.  But it does know where you should go next: you should go talk to google's NS records, and those are listed in the authority section.  And the additional section contains information about the addresses for google's name servers.

Comment: Thanks. I get it. So is it normally for sites such as google, ebay or yahoo to not having any nameservers information in Authority section?

Comment: Everyone has authoritative servers.  However, sometimes you may not get authoritative information in the answer unless you're asking some resolvers or asking their parent (ask .com for google.com's A record and you'll get the authoritative servers in response).

Answer (score 0):

The Authority Section reflects the information of nameservers.

If you using UNIX like operating systems, you can use Dig to traceroute a website.